# In PostgreSQL is there a way to rank/weigh columns so as to order the results?

Tags: postgresql, order-by

Let's say I am searching through three text columns. I don't just want results that match a given word or phrase, but I also want to weigh them (`column A > column B > column C`) - thereby ordering the results such that those rows matching the word in column `A` will come up higher than those matching in column `B`, and those matching in column `B` will come up higher than those matching in column `C`.

Is this possible? Can you provide me with some terminology or suggestions for further reading?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Full text search**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING) has detailed weighting mechanisms.

For simple pattern matching:

```
SELECT *
FROM   t
WHERE  col_a ILIKE '%keyword%' OR
       col_b ILIKE '%keyword%' OR
       col_c ILIKE '%keyword%' 
ORDER  BY col_a ILIKE '%keyword%' OR NULL
        , col_b ILIKE '%keyword%' OR NULL
        , col_c ILIKE '%keyword%' OR NULL;
```

I don't use `col_a  ILIKE '%keyword%' DESC`, because that would sort NULL columns first. We want to treat `NULL` just like `FALSE`, which is achieved this way.

Comment: I prefer `ORDER BY ... NULLS LAST` over an "implicit" sort.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Except that it would be *wrong* in this case. We do *not* want to sort nulls last. We want to treat `NULL` and `FALSE` identically.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of any specific functions to read about, but common tricks might do.

something like this should work:

```
select * from T
where 
ColA like '%my_search_field%' OR
ColB like '%my_search_field%' 
ORDER BY
(case when ColA like '%my_search_field%' then 1 else 0 end) desc,
(case when ColB like '%my_search_field%' then 1 else 0 end) desc;
```

The case statements might need to be in the select list as well.

an alternative:

```
select * from 
(select 1 as rnk,colA,colB from T where colA like '%my_search_field%' 
union all
select 2 as rnk,colA,colB from T where colB like '%my_search_field%' and colA not like '%my_search_field%'
) itab
order by rnk asc;
```

Comment: The second form might produce duplicate rows.

Comment: Easily fixed (probably at the cost of performance) by changing `union all` to `union`. Unfortunately, even in 2014 DBMSes are pretty lousy at optimizing queries with set operators.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: `UNION` would remove dupes, but defy the purpose of the query by twisting the sort order. So, no, it would be wrong.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: correct, didn't take that into account. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @r.m: The edit fixes the dupes (mostly - doesn't work for `NULL`), but the sort order is still sub-optimal. I'd assume a match on both `colA` and `colB` should sort before a match on just `colA`. That's what your first query achieves nicely (equivalent to my later answer), but not the second.